# Rotating orthophoto based on polygon boundary (rotated pixel)?

Tags: software-recommendations, vector-tiles, pixel, rotate, orthophoto

When I clip an orthophoto using a vector polygon, the resulting pixels orientation is north-up like as shown in the graphic below. I used Global Mapper, ERDAS, Arcmap "Clip" "Extract by Mask", "Extract by polygon" and all of them outputs North-up pixels which ends up in big files

[image: North-up pixel - red boundary]

What I am trying to accomplish is to rotate the pixels based on the polygon boundary as shown in the image below.This task is accomplished by software called SOCET SET and the result is a much smaller file in size.

[image]

Does anybody know if there is another software besides SOCET SET that can rotate the pixel based on a rotated rectangular vector polygon?

Answer (score 1):

Pixels can't really be rotated. SOCKET SET obviously rotates the image on the client side instead of making the TIFF file to have physically north up pixels. You can get a neat line with clients that support on-the-fly re-projection, like QGIS, if you keep the image in the original CRS but change the project to use the desired CRS. In this example an that is natively in one UTM zone is projeted into another UTM zone on-the-fly.

[image]